# Integrate Magento 2 into WordPress when WordPress 404 error thrown

Tags: magento2, wordpress

I would like to integrate Magento 2 into WordPress.

What I want is to load Magento 2 before any WordPress 404 error thrown.

I put Magento 2 under `shop` folder from root directory. Then if I go to http://magento2.dev/shop/, I can view the normal Magento front-end. Magento Admin page is http://magento2.dev/shop/cms. Every Magento stuff works fine under `shop` folder.

```
       function wpd_do_stuff_on_404( $preempt, $wp_query ) {
            load_magento();
        }

        add_filter( 'pre_handle_404', 'wpd_do_stuff_on_404', 10, 2 );
```

The above code is to load Magento 2 before WordPress 404 error thrown.

```
    function load_magento() {
        require_once __DIR__ . '/../../shop/app/bootstrap.php';

        $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
        $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');

        \Magento\Framework\Profiler::start('magento');
        $response = $app->launch();

        $magento_http_status = $response->getHeader('Status');
        $magento_header_location = $response->getHeader('Location');
        $magento_content = $response->getContent();
        \Magento\Framework\Profiler::stop('magento');

        var_dump($magento_content);die;
    }
```

I try to browse to http://magento2.dev/men/tops-men/jackets-men, then the above script is run. However, `$magento_content` is always empty string. I expect the full page of html returned.

I try to dump `$response->__toString()` and I get

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found Location: http://magento2.dev/shop/men/tops-men/jackets-men/ pragma: no-cache Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store expires: Tue, 31 Jul 2018 07:22:30 GMT
```

Does anyone have any idea how to return the html correctly?

Comment: HTTP 302 is a redirect. which is what you should do

Comment: @PhilippSander how to force Magento not to redirect from ```/men/tops-men/jackets-men/``` to ```/shop/men/tops-men/jackets-men/```